# How can I get a parameter of an url with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, keyword-argument, django-viewsets

I am building a map with different station location.
The stations belong to different fields.
I have to show all station and, I have all station of a field.

At some point my api is called

```
"""Markers API URL Configuration."""
# Maps with Django (2)
# https://www.paulox.net/2021/07/19/maps-with-django-part-2-geodjango-postgis-and-leaflet/
from rest_framework import routers
from map.viewsets import MarkerViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"map", MarkerViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

then the MarkerViewSet is called (viewsets.py)

```
class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """Marker view set."""
    #print(self.kwargs.get('idfield'))
    bbox_filter_field = "location"
    filter_backends = (filters.InBBoxFilter,)
    queryset = Stations.objects.filter(station_active=1, map=1)
    serializer_class = StationsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        #field_id = self.kwargs['idfield']
        #print("pp:", self.kwargs)
        return Stations.objects.filter(fields_id_field=1)
```

The code above works, but it only show the markers of the field 1

If I change this to 2

```
return Stations.objects.filter(fields_id_field=2)
```

It show all station of the field with the id 2

My url is as the follwoing http://127.0.0.1:8080/map/ to print all stations of all fields.
If I want to have the stations of the field 1, my url will be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/map/1/field
```

and for the field 2 and 4

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/map/2/field
http://127.0.0.1:8080/map/4/field
```

My problem, I can not not and I do not know of to get the id 1,2,4 or another form my url

this does not work

```
#field_id = self.kwargs['idfield']
#print("pp:", self.kwargs)
```

Here is my [map/urls.py](https://github.com/ecosensors/Django/blob/main/EcoSensors/console/map/urls.py)
an my project [urls.py](https://github.com/ecosensors/Django/blob/main/EcoSensors/console/console/urls.py)

Should I try to get the id of the field from the viewsets.py or how would you suggest me to archive my goal?

EDIT:
[Here is my views.py](https://github.com/ecosensors/Django/blob/main/EcoSensors/console/map/views.py#L32). Here I can get idfield
Would it have a way to pass it [my viewsets.py](https://github.com/ecosensors/Django/blob/main/EcoSensors/console/map/viewsets.py#L12)?

Comment: You should pass a `?` after the `/` to get the parameter. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/map/2/?some_field=field` then `request.GET.get("some_field", None)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Args**
I believe you API urls should be as follows

1. `/maps/` --> returns a list of objects
2. `/maps/<id>/` --> returns a single object

If you do this you should be able to get results according to the given `id` (if primary key) without doing anything in your view. `viewsets` automatically returns an object based on the [`lookup field`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/). If it is not a primary key you can set different lookup field.

**Kwargs**
in kwargs your URL should be as `/maps/?idfield=<id>`, then you will be able to do the followings.

`kwargs` from GET request can be obtained as below

```
request.GET.get("idfield")
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, but how can I insert the request.GET.get()? I tried to modified [this]{https://github.com/ecosensors/Django/blob/main/EcoSensors/console/map/viewsets.py#L20) but I am not sure where should I declare request

Comment: please check my updated answer, i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that your proposition only works in views.py as it start with

```
def field(request, idfield):
    request.GET.get("idfield")
```

isn't?

I am working with a viewsets.py starting with

```
class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """Marker view set."""
    bbox_filter_field = "location"
    filter_backends = (filters.InBBoxFilter,)
    queryset = Stations.objects.filter(station_active=1, map=1)
    serializer_class = StationsSerializer
    """
    def get_tags(self):
        return Stations.objects.filter(fields_id_field=1)
    """
    def get_queryset(self):
        #field_id = self.kwargs['idfield']
        #print("ppp:", self.kwargs['idfield'])
        return Stations.objects.filter(fields_id_field=1)
```

I do know where your proposition could be added.

However, I think I am getting close to the solution, but I still get error.

I hope you can help me

First, in my map.js file. I added

```
async function load_markers() {
    const markers_url = `/api/map/1/`; // LOOK AT THIS LINE
    console.log("markers_url: ",markers_url);
    const response = await fetch(markers_url);
    //console.log("response: ",response);
    const geojson = await response.json();
    console.log("geojson: ",geojson);
    return geojson;
}
```

In my urls.py file, I changed to

```
path("api/<int:idf>/", include("map.api")),
```

which will redirect to the api.py file. I think, all is correct until this point, isn't?

In my api.py file, I have tried serveral things getting inspirated from the [django-rest-framework -  router page](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage)

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
#router.register(r"map", MarkerViewSet) #INITIAL
#router.register(r"^map/{idf}/$", MarkerViewSet) #I tried this
#router.register(r"^map/(?P<idf>[0-9]+)/$", MarkerViewSet) #this generate an error because of idf 
router.register(r"^map/(?P<id_f>[0-9]+)/$", MarkerViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Another error message is on Firefox:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICZGQ.png)

I believe, I should find the right format, but something else should be wrong

Many thanks for your help